# Magento 2.4.2 address on storeview level although customer config is Account Sharing Options not global

Tags: magento2, multistore, customer-account, store-view, shipping-address

I have a Magento 2.4.2 with 3 websites, 1 B2C and 2 B2B shops.
I have setup the global customer setup to Share Customer Accounts -> Per Website

But when I want to add an customer address the inputs is displaying

Storeviews
[image]

Where does this come from ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue for me was that a 3rd party module added the store view dropdown on checkout. I'd suggest searching the database for the name of the element. Once found, there should be a column, is_visible, setting this to 0 should remove it from the front end. In Magento Open Source we can't see customer attributes in the admin panel. This is why we must use the database.